# allocating an object of abstract class type error

Tags: c++, abstract-class

Hi I'm getting the following error and am really unsure why.

```
class InteSiVis: public ofBaseApp //{
,  public ofxMidiListener{
```

This occurs when I make class inresivis inherit from the ofxMidiListener class and I get the following error in the main source file

int main( ){

```
ofSetupOpenGL(1920,1080, OF_WINDOW);            
ofRunApp( new InteSiVis()); // <-------- The error is here Allocating object of type abstract
```

}

This is really confusing as I have tried this with another example in the exact way and do not get this error.

```
class testApp : public ofBaseApp, public ofxMidiListener {

int main(){
    ofSetupOpenGL(640, 480, OF_WINDOW);
    ofRunApp(new testApp());
}
```

Could you give me an idea as to why I'm getting this error I'm calling the class in the exact same way. Thanks in advance.

///----------------------------------Edit
InteSiVis.h

```
class InteSiVis: public ofBaseApp //{
,  public ofxMidiListener{

public:
    InteSiVis() ;

    void setup();
    void update();
    void draw();
    void exit();

    void keyPressed(int key);
    void keyReleased(int key);

    // Make an Array of Particle Systems
    vector<FluidBodySim> mArrayFluidBodySim;

    FluidBodySim        mFluidBodySim       ;   ///< Simulation of fluid and rigid bodies

    int                 mStatusWindow       ;   ///< Identifier for status window
    unsigned            mFrame              ;   ///< Frame counter
    double              mTimeNow            ;   ///< Current virtual time
    int                 mMouseButtons[3]    ;   ///< Mouse buttons pressed
    bool                mInitialized        ;   ///< Whether this application has been initialized
    int                 mScenario           ;   ///< Which scenario is being simulated now

// Scene stuff
    ofEasyCam mEasyCam;
    ofLight light;

// Setting Shader stuff
    ofShader shader;
    ofxPostProcessing post;

// Sound

    float   * lAudioOut; /* outputs */
    float   * rAudioOut;

    float * lAudioIn; /* inputs */
    float * rAudioIn;

    int     initialBufferSize; /* buffer size */
    int     sampleRate;

    double wave,sample,outputs[2];

    maxiSample piano_A1, piano_AS1, piano_B1, piano_C1, piano_CS1, piano_D1, piano_DS1, piano_E1, piano_F1, piano_FS1, piano_G1, piano_GS1;

    vector<maxiPitchStretch<grainPlayerWin>*> stretches;

    maxiPitchStretch<grainPlayerWin> *ts, *ts2, *ts3, *ts4, *ts5;

    int nAverages;
    float *ifftOutput;
    int ifftSize;

//    // Playing the Wav Files
    void audioOut(float *output, int bufferSize, int nChannels);

    double speed, grainLength, rate;

    ofxMaxiFFT fft;
    ofxMaxiFFTOctaveAnalyzer oct;
    int current;
    double pos;


} ;
```

testApp.h

```
class testApp : public ofBaseApp, public ofxMidiListener {

public:

    void setup();
    void draw();
    void exit();

    void keyPressed(int key);
    void keyReleased(int key);

    void mouseMoved(int x, int y );
    void mouseDragged(int x, int y, int button);
    void mousePressed(int x, int y, int button);
    void mouseReleased();


    stringstream text;

    vector<ParticleSystem> ps;

    //----------------------Sound---------------------------

    void newMidiMessage(ofxMidiMessage& eventArgs);


    ofxMidiIn midiIn;
    ofxMidiOut midiOut;
    ofxMidiMessage midiMessage;

    void audioOut(float *output, int bufferSize, int nChannnels);

};
```

//----------------VIRTUAL FUNCTION
vorticitydistribution.h

```
class IVorticityDistribution
{
    public:
        virtual Vec3 GetDomainSize( void ) const = 0 ;
        virtual void AssignVorticity( Vec3 & vorticity , const Vec3 & position , const Vec3 & vCenter ) const = 0 ;
} ;

class JetRing : public IVorticityDistribution
{
    public:
        /*! \brief Initialize parameters for a vortex ring (using a different formula from the other).

            The vorticity profile resulting from this is such that the induced velocity is in [0,1].

            \param fRadiusSlug - radius of central region where velocity is constant

            \param fThickness - thickness of vortex ring, i.e. radius of annular core

            \param vDirection - vector of ring axis, also vector of propagation

            \param fSpeed   - speed of slug

        */
        JetRing( const float & fRadiusSlug , const float & fThickness , const Vec3 & vDirection )
            : mRadiusSlug( fRadiusSlug )
            , mThickness( fThickness )
            , mRadiusOuter( mRadiusSlug + mThickness )
            , mDirection( vDirection )
        {
        }

        virtual Vec3 GetDomainSize( void ) const
        {
            const float boxSideLength   = 2.f * ( mRadiusOuter ) ;    // length of side of virtual cube
            return Vec3( 1.0f , 1.0f , 1.0f ) * boxSideLength ;
        }

        virtual void AssignVorticity( Vec3 & vorticity , const Vec3 & position , const Vec3 & vCenter ) const
        {

} ;
```

Comment: You cannot `new Type()` if the class definition contains pure virtual methods.

Comment: Did you override all pure virtual methods from both your base classes ?

Comment: That isn't the only error message. The *reason* (a failure to provide implementation to "something") should be present as well. Read on.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is how things works:

```
class Base
{
        public:
         const std::string SayHi() { return "Hi"; } // a normal non-virtual method            
         virtual std::string GetName() { return ("Base"); } // a normal virtual method
         virtual int GetValue() = 0; // a pure virtual method
};
```

When you declare testApp like this `class testApp : public Base { ... };`:

> **normal non-virtual methods** are inherited as they are declared inside Base, and are immutable.
>
> **normal virtual methods** are inherited as they are declared inside Base, you can use them >as they already are declared, or redefine them to fit a particular purpose.
>
> **pure virtual methods** are not defined, the parent class only say "if you inherit from me you HAVE TO implement those by yourself, strictly matching my prototype (How I defined them)

If you don't follow those rules, you'll get errors.

---

Now, you have to be sure that there is no pure virtual methodes inside **ofBaseApp** neither **ofxMidiListener** that are not implemented into the children class.

Since you state that class **testApp** doesnt do any error, you must have a pure virtual methods in **InteSiVis** from the parents classes that you forgot to implement.

Comment: I haven't got a virtual method in the inteSiVis class but I do have a few in the the rest of my code which is being called by the InteSiVis class. Is this the reason why?

Comment: what's an alternative to using the virtual class?

Comment: No, using them is a good thing if you respect the usage.

Do you also call the same "rest of the code" you call in InteSiVis in testApp?

Comment: no, testApp is just a test for the midi device, InteSiVis uses a lot more methods which uses a few virtual methods such as ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------class                                                     IVorticityDistribution
{
    public:
        virtual Vec3 GetDomainSize( void ) const = 0 ;
        virtual void AssignVorticity( Vec3 & vorticity , const Vec3 & position , const Vec3 & vCenter ) const = 0 ;
} ;

Comment: I'm using a fluid simulation in the InteSiVis.h whereas testApp.h just uses a simple particle system

Comment: Yes, so the problem sits here imo. If you inherit from a class having some pure virtual member function, you have to implement them in the children class. If you don't want them it's a deisgn problem, but in order to compile you either have to implement them or change the object you inherit from.

Comment: Did you understand or do I have to edit my asnwer? If you need more explanation tell me and wait for ithe edit, I'll try to explain what I think the problem is more precisly than in my comment.

Comment: I don't understand sorry

Comment: okay I see what you mean. However how do I implement the virtual functions in the child class? I've edited my question so you can see where I call a virtual function.

Comment: Hum it depend of the context and of the purpose of this function, it looks context dependent I can't help you on that, refer to the documentation of the api you are using

Comment: ah really? do you know any other ways to listen to midi data without it being a child class from the base class?

Comment: I think you don't get me, I can help with c++ problem, context free example. I don't know if your code is used for midi listening or anything else.

Comment: okay, I'm sorry, I understand. Sorry I was just wondering if that was part of the problem and running out of ideas

Comment: I got rid of the virtual function and it works! THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP AND SORRY FOR BEING A NOOOB!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you haven't posted enough information to be sure.

Typically when you get a message that the compiler is unable to create a class of abstract type where you are trying to instantiate a class which inherits from some interface, it means that you have not provided an implementation of one of the purely virtual methods specified by the interface.

In your implementation of testApp, have you specified an overide of any methods which you have not specified in InteSiVis?  The signatures *must match exactly*.  If they differ by a const, by a ref, a pointer, or any other way, you will get this error.

If this does not solve your problem, please post more complete information.  At least the signatures of what have implemented in InteSiVis and testApp.

Comment: I've edited the question with full information as to what's in the .h file. I have used some virtual methods, so how to I change using them?

Comment: You don't listen to commentaries, seeing at the two implementations (testApp and InteSiVis) InteSiVis implement way more methods, so we think that you must have ommited some pure virtual methods implementations in testApp. Can you check that and come back to us?

Comment: If you aren't able to check that or if you dont understand just add the **ofBaseApp** and **ofxMidiListener** declarations.

Comment: yes, the vorticityDistribution is only being used in InteSiVis, and that's where there are virtual functions

Comment: "you are trying to instantiate a class which inherits from some interface, it means that you have not provided an implementation of one of the purely virtual methods specified by the interface." This is bit of a lazy answer. The problem is that `FluidBodySim` is likely the abstract class and std::vector doesn't like that. Coming from javascript it is kind of sad that even in C++ people give answer like "just turn it off and on and. see what happens". If I hadn't already done that that I wouldn't ask or search on SO.